# In Active Directory Users and Computers, can you display the DNS name instead of NetBIOS?

Tags: active-directory

In Active Directory Users and Computers, the computer names are listed as their NetBIOS (Computer name) names not their DNS or the computer name that is actually used for the machine. So in ADUC the column "Name" displays the NetBIOS name, but **is it possible to have it display the full computer name instead of the NetBios name** which truncates the full name?

The domain is Windows Server 2003 functional level.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Wouldn't that be redundant because almost always all member machines should have same domain name?

Answer (score 2):

Not AFAIK. My guess is it's because the Computer Name/Host Name (the NetBIOS name) is a system property and the FQDN is not. You can verify this by running `systeminfo` from a command line and looking at the Host Name property or by running `set` from a command line and looking at the COMPUTERNAME property.

Comment: Command `systeminfo` reports **Host Name:** as the truncated NetBIOS name. The command `hostname` reports the full name. I'm currently using a longer than 15 character naming convention and this doesn't display well in AD. Bummer.

Comment: @PawełCzopowik `I'm currently using a longer than 15 character naming convention and this doesn't display well in AD` It doesn't work well or at all in AD, either.  `computer1234567`, `computer12345678`, `computer123456789`, `computer1234567890` (and so on) are all the same computer account in Active Directory.  And there can be only one account with the same name, so if you join 4 computers with those 4 names to Active Directory, you will end up with 1 functional computer and 3 that will throw a broken trust relationship error when you try to login.  **You're doing it wrong, please stop.**